# Jquery: sum input text fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, sum

I have a table including input text fields with the basic structure below. I am having trouble building a function to iterate all rows in the table and sum all the values of input fields beginning with BFObel where the value of the field beginning with BFOkto are the same. So for the basic example below the sum for value 1111 would be 2000 and the sum for value 1112 would be 3000. Each sum would then be written to an inputfield with the id field1111, field1112 etc...

```
<table>
  <tr id="BFOrow1">
    <td><input type="text" id="BFOtxt1" value="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="BFOkto1" value="1111" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="BFObel1" value="1000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="BFOrow2">
    <td><input type="text" id="BFOtxt2" value="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="BFOkto2" value="1111" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="BFObel2" value="1000" /></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr id="BFOrow3">
    <td><input type="text" id="BFOtxt3" value="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="BFOkto3" value="1112" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="BFObel3" value="1000" /></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr id="BFOrow4">
    <td><input type="text" id="BFOtxt4" value="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="BFOkto4" value="1112" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="BFObel4" value="1000" /></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr id="BFOrow5">
    <td><input type="text" id="BFOtxt5" value="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="BFOkto5" value="1112" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="BFObel5" value="1000" /></td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: You need to phrase your question better and post some html

Comment: Since you're computing several sums, what do you intend to do with the results? Should they e.g. be returned in an array, or stored in the rows themselves as attributes / data?

Comment: Each sum will be written to another input field with the id like 1111 or 1112

Comment: do you mean you want to fetch the unique values within the `BFOkto*` elements first? Also, HTML 4 and lower does not allow numbers as ids, won't that be a problem?

Comment: @ Frédédric, not sure where to begin. I have been trying iterating each row first but haven't found a good solution. As for the html4 numbers you are correct. The input fields I use actually are named like field1111, field1112 etc...

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use an object literal to track your results and an ["attribute starts with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to find the text inputs:

```
var accumulator = { };
$('table input[id^=BFOkto]').each(function() {
    var sum_id = this.id.replace(/^BFOkto/, 'BFObel');
    if(!accumulator[this.value])
        accumulator[this.value] = 0;
    accumulator[this.value] += parseInt($('#' + sum_id).val(), 10);
});
// accumulator now has your results.
```

Don't forget the second argument to [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) so that you don't get tripped up by values with leading zeros (which look like octal without a specified radix).

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/QAqsQ/ (you'll need to run this in a browser with an open JavaScript console to see the resulting `accumulator`).

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum1111 = 0;

$('input[value="1111"]').each(function() {
  var ordinal = $(this).attr('id').replace('BFOkto', '');
  sum1111 += parseInt($('#BFObel' + ordinal).val());
});
```

At the end, sum1111 should equal 2000.

For reuse, wrap the logic in a function:

```
function getSum(BFOkto) {
    var sum = 0;
    var ordinal = null;

    $('input[value="' + BFOkto + '"]').each(function() {
      ordinal = $(this).attr('id').replace('BFOkto', '');
      sum += parseInt($('#BFObel' + ordinal).val());
    });

    return sum;
}
```

And then call:

```
getSum('1111');
getSum('1112');
```

Comment: In my case the value is not known from the beginning (depends on user input) so I need a function that can be used for unknown values/selectors.

Comment: ok, then replace getSum('1111') with getSum($('#BFOkto1').val())

Answer (score 0):

A different approach: find all input fields with prefix BFOkto, for each, find the input with prefix BFObel sharing same parent and accumulate its value

```
ref = $("table td input[id^=BFOkto]");

var sums = new Object();
ref.each(function(){
    val = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find("td input[id^=BFObel]").val(), 10);
    property = 'i'+ this.value;
    sums[property] = (sums[property] || 0 ) + val;
});

alert(sums['i1111']);
alert(sums['i1112']);
```

sums will be an object with properties

```
i1111 = 2000
i1112 = 3000
```

Despite javascript allows it, it is better not to use pure numeric properties for objects (associative arrays), hence the i prefix

The running example is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/TbSau/1/